# Write data form specific csv cell to another file with python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, readfile

I have data in a csv file and need to put the content of specific cells in other files. Here is a simplified version of the csv file.

```
A;B;C;D
A1;B1;C1;D1
A2;B2;C2;D2
A3;B3;C3;D3
A4;B4;C4;D4
```

The csv file should be converted into a twodimensional array, preferably with numpy. After that the data from the array should be written into some other files. Here is a snippet of the simplified code.

```
import numpy
table = numpy.genfromtxt('table.csv', delimiter=';', skip_header=1)

for row in range (4):
    output = open('array %s.txt' %(row+1), 'w')
    for clmn in range (4):
        output.write('%s' %table[row][clmn])

output.close()
```

I have been struggeling finding out a proper way to put the data in the array. Any ideas how this could be realised or have you found any mistakes I made?

---

Edit: I have found the problem.
`numpy` was not properly installed.
I also had to make some tweaks to the code.

```
import numpy

#get table size
table = numpy.genfromtxt('table.csv', delimiter=';')
rows, cols = table.shape

#get table data
table = numpy.recfromtxt('table.csv', delimiter=';', dtype=str)

#write table in different files
for row in range(rows):
    output = open('array %s.txt' %row, 'w')
    for clmn in range(cols):
        output.write('%s\t' %table[row][clmn])
    output.close()
```

This is the new code and it outputs the files as intended

array 0.txt `A  B   C   D`

array 1.txt `A1 B1  C1  D1`

array 2.txt `A2 B2  C2  D2`

array 3.txt `A3 B3  C3  D3`

array 4.txt `A4 B4  C4  D4`

Comment: What format do you want to get in the archives?

Comment: what is wrong with this code? btw `output.close()` should be inside for loop

Comment: The archives would contain the data from the table inbetween some text. But this is irrelevant for my question because that is not the problem.

The problem is that there has to be somewhere an error because the output files are not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

output.close() must be in the loop, Try with it:

```
import numpy

table = numpy.genfromtxt('table.csv', delimiter=';', skip_header=1)
rows, cols = table.shape
for row in range(rows):
    output = open('array %s.txt' % (row + 1), 'w')
    for clmn in range(cols):
        output.write('%s\t' % table[row][clmn])

    output.close()
```

Comment: I like the idea with the `rows` and `cols` variables. This simplifies my program quite a bit :). But your code does not create any output files either. Maybe I am doing something wrong, other than the code itsef?

Comment: To me if I create the files

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the numpy array, something like this might work for you.

```
import csv

with open('table.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
   reader = list(csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';'))

   # skips header line
   for row in range(1, len(reader)):
      with open('array %s.txt' % row, 'w') as out_file:
         for i in reader[row]:
            # Modify this line to change what the output file contains
            out_file.write('%s' % i)
```

Comment: Your code does also not create any output files. I asume I am doing something else wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: I missed typed a word, try again? it makes files on my machine with python 3

Answer (score 0):

You can write a csv with `np.savetxt`;

For example, taking your example as literal (is it really floats?)

```
In [1]: txt = b"""A;B;C;D
   ...: A1;B1;C1;D1
   ...: A2;B2;C2;D2
   ...: A3;B3;C3;D3
   ...: A4;B4;C4;D4
   ...: """.splitlines()

In [7]: table= np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter=';',skip_header=1,dtype='U2')
In [8]: table
Out[8]: 
array([['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'],
       ['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'],
       ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3'],
       ['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4']], 
      dtype='<U2')
In [9]: np.savetxt('test.csv',table,header='A,B,C,D',delimiter=',',fmt='%3s')
In [10]: cat test.csv
# A,B,C,D
 A1, B1, C1, D1
 A2, B2, C2, D2
 A3, B3, C3, D3
 A4, B4, C4, D4
```

Here I've written the same values back out, with different delimiter and formatting.

`savetxt` does, basically

```
 for row in table:
    f.write(fmt%tuple(row))
```

where `fmt` is one you provide in full, or created from your `fmt`:

```
In [11]: np.savetxt('test.csv',table,header='A,B,C,D',fmt='%s %s  %s   %s')
In [12]: cat test.csv
# A,B,C,D
A1 B1  C1   D1
...
```

So you could modify your write along these lines:

```
In [13]: for row in table:
    ...:     print('%s %s,%s;%s'%tuple(row))
    ...:     
A1 B1,C1;D1
A2 B2,C2;D2
A3 B3,C3;D3
A4 B4,C4;D4
```